# How to mount path of c:\ programmatically in android?

Tags: android

I am using emulator to run my application. How to i mount my computer drives c:\ path. Because i need to access directly files from c:\ to my android emulator. Your comments and answers all are valuable me. Thanks.

Comment: And what if the PC doesn't have a C: path? And what if they don't even have Windows? You probably want to refrase your questions as "mount a PC filesystem path from Android app".

Comment: Unless you are making an app that is specifically going to access your computer this is most likely not what you want. Instead, you should move any files to be used in your app to the assets or resources directory in your project. If you want to use files on the phone that is not bundled with your project, move them to your sd-card (either by mounting as a disk and moving manually or by using ddms to push files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access C: drive directly in android.

because c: drive is not a part of your mobile device.

If files are static you can put that files in
 `assets` or `row` folder

Comment: You can if you write PC-side software to run with your app.

Comment: @m0skit0: can u explain how and if have done then how plz tell me

Comment: I've never done it, but shouldn't be too hard. Other apps do. You just read the filesystem with your PC-side software and send it through whatever communication mean you want (USB, Wifi, 3G...) to the Android-side software. You can think of it as a client-server software.

Comment: @m0skit0 - making a server side application on your system, which maintain all file-structure of system, then in your android application write client side code, which will connect to server and access all file either by ftp:// or http://..

Comment: ya thats the point you have to user either URL of server or either IP of current PC but could not use directly like c:/xyz..
m i rite ?

Comment: That's what I'm saying user370305. I don't care what communication means you want to use, as he didn't specify so.

Comment: Yes, directly the system path is not accessible, becoz android can't recognized the system path.

Comment: You're wrong because you say you can't do that in Android. That's plain wrong. You indeed can, check the other answers.

Comment: @user370305: wrong, you can access whatever path you like. Read my answer.

Comment: ya u can't read c:/xyz in android ? if u can just give me code

Comment: server client and c:/xyz are diff things

Comment: Thanks. Your all comments are valuable me.

Comment: @gtumca-MAC: nonsense. To access any filesystem you're using client-server architetcure, even in local (app -> OS kernel).  And this is voted as right answer, OMG... Completely useless.

Answer (score 1):

Android has its own `File System`. So you can not access your System path like `"c:\ path "`directly in application.But If you want to access any files from your system then making a `server-client architecture in application` is the options **(Via http:// or ftp://)**.

Comment: Thanks for information. I understand your concept. It's helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate the behavior you want. Create a disk image using [mksdcard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/mksdcard.html), mount it using emulators `-sdcard` option. Finally mount the disk image to your pc as well (a tool like [imdisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk) will do. Then you will have a new drive in your pc, of your choice. You copy the files you want to access to this new drive.

Comment: This is not the question. The question is accessing the PC filesytem. By waking a copy you're not accessing the PC filesystem.

Comment: Well this way he can access. I do not understand why the downvote is for?

Comment: Well, as I said, that way you're not accessing the PC filesystem, **but a copy**. If you don't know what's the difference, then...

Comment: This is actually quite clever, although I think that the op wants to access files from his computer as if its harddrive was the sd card, even though this is an improper practice.

Comment: Clever? Well... What if he wants that for real-time remote file managing? And you have to make an image everytime the filesystem changes? This answer is wrong except some cases where filesystem is relatively static. Other answers are way more dynamic. And again, it's simply not answering the question **because you're not acessing the PC filesystem** (which is the question).

Answer (score -4):

You can't only with Android. You should write a PC-side software and do this through this software to communicate with you Android app.

For example, the PC-side software reads the directory you want to access and sends this information to your listening Android app. This can be thought about as a client-server application, where PC acts as filesystem server, and the Android app as a client app.

An example of this can be the FTP server-client pair.

Comment: Huh? What are you talking about?

Comment: Since my comment has mysteriously disappeared, I'll put it again: **comments for downvoting reasons are welcome**

Comment: Sorry, but his is a help-me-do-it-myself site, and not a make-my-work site. I can help you understand how to make it, but I will definitely not do your work for free (although I might consider if you share profits).